# How to compose two functions together into 1 using FP's compose() javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, lambda, functional-programming, function-composition

How can I compose two functions together into 1 using FP's `compose()`
here's live code: https://repl.it/JXMl/1

I have 3 pure functions:

```
// groups By some unique key
const groupBy = function(xs, key) {
  return xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
    (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
    return rv;
  }, {});
};

// ungroups the group by
const ungroup = (obj) => {
  return Object.keys(obj)
               .map(x => obj[x]);
};

// flatten array
const flatten = (arrs) => {
  return arrs.reduce((acc, item) => acc.concat(item), [])
}
```

And a functional utility compose function from [Functional Jargon](https://github.com/hemanth/functional-programming-jargon#function-composition)

```
const compose = (f, g) => (a) => f(g(a))
```

In the end, I want a `ungroupAndFlatten` function created through `compose()`.

Along the lines of:

```
const ungroupAndFlatten = compose(ungroup, flatten) // Usage doesn't work.
console.log(ungroupAndFlatten(obj))
```

Example code:

```
const arrs = [
  {name: 'abc', effectiveDate: "2016-01-01T00:00:00+00:00"},
  {name: 'abcd', effectiveDate: "2016-02-01T00:00:00+00:00"},
  {name: 'abcd', effectiveDate: "2016-09-01T00:00:00+00:00"},
  {name: 'abc', effectiveDate: "2016-04-01T00:00:00+00:00"},
  {name: 'abc', effectiveDate: "2016-05-01T00:00:00+00:00"},
]; 

const groupedByName = groupBy(arrs, 'name');

// Example Output
//
// var obj = {
//    abc: [
//      { name: 'abc', effectiveDate: '2016-01-01T00:00:00+00:00' },
//      { name: 'abc', effectiveDate: '2016-04-01T00:00:00+00:00' },
//      { name: 'abc', effectiveDate: '2016-05-01T00:00:00+00:00' }
//    ],
//    abcd: [ 
//      { name: 'abcd', effectiveDate: '2016-02-01T00:00:00+00:00' },
//      { name: 'abcd', effectiveDate: '2016-09-01T00:00:00+00:00' }
//    ]
//  }

const ungroupAndFlatten = compose(ungroup, flatten) // Usage doesn't work.
console.log(ungroupAndFlatten(groupedByName)) 

// Output:
//  var arrs = [
//    {name: 'abc', effectiveDate: "2016-01-01T00:00:00+00:00"},
//    {name: 'abcd', effectiveDate: "2016-02-01T00:00:00+00:00"},
//    {name: 'abcd', effectiveDate: "2016-09-01T00:00:00+00:00"},
//    {name: 'abc', effectiveDate: "2016-04-01T00:00:00+00:00"},
//    {name: 'abc', effectiveDate: "2016-05-01T00:00:00+00:00"},
//  ];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you made a simple mistake,you've set ungroup as your f function while it is your g function:

```
const ungroupAndFlatten = compose(flatten, ungroup)
```

switch ungroup and flatten and everything will work fine

Comment: Damn you're right! lol Weird that it goes from right to left and not left to right.

Comment: @MatthewHarwood It goes from right to left because that's how it works in math.

Comment: @ftor could you bring a bit more clarity to the "thats how math goes?" lol  Which math ? 

I see that the compose goes inside out in execution but does the API of compose is trying to mimic that ? right being the inside?

Comment: @MatthewHarwood The right-to-left order has prevailed because the notation gives a nice symmetry in math: `(f∘g)(z) = f(g(z))`. With the inverted order you'd get `(g∗f)(z) = f(g(z))`. That's all.

Answer (score 3):

## Function Composition

The function `compose` has a evaluation order from *right to left*.

```
/*
 * 1. take x
 * 2. execute g(x)
 * 3. take the return value of g(x) and execute f with it
*/
const compose = (f, g) => x => f(g(x))
```

There is another function called `pipe` which evaluates from *left to right*

```
const pipe = (g, f) => x => f(g(x))
```

## Your Code

As already mentioned by [@Nima Hakimi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7809895/nima-hakimi), you have reversed the argument order.

To solve you problem we could

- switch the order of the arguments

  ```
  const ungroupAndFlatten = compose(
      flatten,
      ungroup
  )
  ```

  ```js
  const compose = (f, g) => x => 
      f(g(x))

  const ungroup = obj =>
      Object.keys(obj)
          .map(x => obj[x]);

  const flatten = arrs =>
      arrs.reduce((acc, item) => acc.concat(item), [])

  const groupedByName = {
      abc: [
          { name: 'abc', effectiveDate: '2016-01-01T00:00:00+00:00' },
          { name: 'abc', effectiveDate: '2016-04-01T00:00:00+00:00' },
          { name: 'abc', effectiveDate: '2016-05-01T00:00:00+00:00' }
      ],
      abcd: [
          { name: 'abcd', effectiveDate: '2016-02-01T00:00:00+00:00' },
          { name: 'abcd', effectiveDate: '2016-09-01T00:00:00+00:00' }
      ]
  }

  const ungroupAndFlatten = compose(
      flatten,
      ungroup
  )

  console.log(
    ungroupAndFlatten(groupedByName)
  )
  ```
- or use `pipe`

  ```
  const ungroupAndFlatten = pipe(
      ungroup,
      flatten
  )
  ```

  ```js
  const pipe = (g, f) => x => 
      f(g(x))

  const ungroup = obj =>
      Object.keys(obj)
          .map(x => obj[x]);

  const flatten = arrs =>
      arrs.reduce((acc, item) => acc.concat(item), [])

  const groupedByName = {
      abc: [
          { name: 'abc', effectiveDate: '2016-01-01T00:00:00+00:00' },
          { name: 'abc', effectiveDate: '2016-04-01T00:00:00+00:00' },
          { name: 'abc', effectiveDate: '2016-05-01T00:00:00+00:00' }
      ],
      abcd: [
          { name: 'abcd', effectiveDate: '2016-02-01T00:00:00+00:00' },
          { name: 'abcd', effectiveDate: '2016-09-01T00:00:00+00:00' }
      ]
  }

  const ungroupAndFlatten = pipe(
      ungroup,
      flatten
  )

  console.log(
    ungroupAndFlatten(groupedByName)
  )
  ```

## Function Composition with `n` Arguments

And again we have

- compose

  ```
  const compose = (...fns) => fns.reduceRight((f, g) => (...args) => 
      g(f(...args)))
  ```
- pipe

  ```
  const pipe = (...fns) => fns.reduce((f, g) => (...args) => 
      g(f(...args)))
  ```

Our goal is it to compose to `ungroup` and `flatten` the function `groupBy`, too.
We could try

```
const groupByNameAndFlattenAndUngroup = compose(
    flatten,
    ungroup,
    groupBy('name', x)  // <-- this is our problem
)
```

but this will not work. We can only compose functions with one argument.. The solution is to rewrite `groupBy` to a *curried* version:

```
const groupBy = xs => key =>
xs.reduce((rv, x) => {
    (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x)
    return rv
}, {})

const groupByNameAndFlattenAndUngroup = (key, xs) => compose(
    flatten,
    ungroup,
    groupBy ('name')
) (xs)
```

But this solution can be even shorter. If we switch the order of the arguments from `groupBy` to  `groupBy = key => xs => {/*..*/}` we can do:

```
const groupBy = key => xs =>
    xs.reduce((rv, x) => {
        (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x)
        return rv
    }, {})

const groupByNameAndFlattenAndUngroup = compose(
    flatten,
    ungroup,
    groupBy ('name')
)
```

## Working Example

```js
const arrs = [
  {name: 'abc', effectiveDate: "2016-01-01T00:00:00+00:00"},
  {name: 'abcd', effectiveDate: "2016-02-01T00:00:00+00:00"},
  {name: 'abcd', effectiveDate: "2016-09-01T00:00:00+00:00"},
  {name: 'abc', effectiveDate: "2016-04-01T00:00:00+00:00"},
  {name: 'abc', effectiveDate: "2016-05-01T00:00:00+00:00"},
]

const compose = (...fns) => fns.reduceRight((f, g) => (...args) => 
    g(f(...args)))
    
const ungroup = obj =>
    Object.keys(obj)
        .map(x => obj[x]);

const flatten = arrs =>
    arrs.reduce((acc, item) => acc.concat(item), [])
    
const groupBy = key => xs =>
  xs.reduce((rv, x) => {
      (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x)
      return rv
  }, {})
  
const groupByName = groupBy ('name')
const groupByEffectiveDate = groupBy ('effectiveDate')
  
const groupByNameAndFlattenAndUngroup = compose(
    flatten,
    ungroup,
    groupByName
)

const groupBygroupByEffectiveDateAndFlattenAndUngroup = compose(
    flatten,
    ungroup,
    groupByEffectiveDate
)

console.log(
  groupByNameAndFlattenAndUngroup (arrs)
)

console.log(
  groupBygroupByEffectiveDateAndFlattenAndUngroup (arrs)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ungroup and flatten in a single function.

```
const ungroupAndFlatten = (obj) => Object.keys(obj).reduce((a, k) => {obj[k].forEach(e => a.push(e)); return a}, [])
```